# put condition depending on the value HIGHCHARTS

Tags: javascript, css, charts, highcharts

I want that if the value is below 300, the align must be "right" and the color of the bar will be yellow.

I need to make this condition for each category. But, I do not know how to do it.

http://jsfiddle.net/pb1q9wzk/

```
plotOptions: {
            bar: {
                dataLabels: {
                padding:0,
                allowOverlap:true,
                    enabled: true,
                    align: 'left',
                    color: '#FFFFFF',
                    inside: true,
                    crop: false,
                    overflow:"none",
                        formatter: function() {

                    return this.series.name+ " "+ this.y;

                    console.log(this.series.name);
                },
                    style:{
                        width:100
                    }

                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

I can at least solve half the problem. But couldn't figure out, how to bind the text alignment to the value.

**Yellow bar if value below 300**

Use the `zones` property inside **every** series:

```
      series: [{
          name: 'bar3',
          data: [600,540,535,500,0],
          color: "#00FF00",

          // Append this to each series:
          zones: [{
            // Make it yellow if <= 300
            color: '#f0e600',
            value: 300
          }]
        }]
```